# Linear mixed model with repeated Anova issue

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models

I have a question related to repeated Anova with Linear mixed model. I have found a nice example posted very long time ago on another website (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237512/how-to-perform-post-hoc-test-on-lmer-model) but I am not sure if this method is correct for my case.

```
library (lme4)
library (lmerTest)
Result<- lmer (Value~Type+ (1|Material), data = data)
summary (Result)
library(multcomp)
summary(glht(Results, linfct = mcp(Material= "Tukey")), test = adjusted("holm"))
```

The person who gave this example mentioned: "After you've fit your lmer model you can do ANOVA, MANOVA, and multiple comparison procedures on the model object". Briefly, I have repeated measurements of 6 groups and I want to see which material differs from which material. When I run this code I see the results I am looking for but I would like to ask if this method can be used for repeated anova or should I use different library? in that case I would be happy if you can edit the code. Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

Comment: Could you provide more details on your research question? You have one independent variable—which is categorical and has six levels, correct? You basically want to look at pairwise comparisons between *all* of these? Lastly, is `Type` a Level 1 or Level 2 variable?

Comment: Lets say I have 2 plastic components (native) and I perform compression. Then, putting the 'x' material between the plastic and performing the same test protocol, and reperforming same for each material. This is Repeated measurement. Material and Type is Factor instead of categorical.  So basically I want to perform Tukey to  see which one differs from which one. But I am not sure if I should use multcomp or anova? I don't know what do change if I want to apply anova or manova to the code?   `library(multcomp)
summary(glht(Results, linfct = mcp(Material= "Tukey")), test = adjusted("holm"))`

Comment: Thank you for your time @MarkWhite